# Python\SQLite: table A has no column named X

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a table named A which I have created and needs data to be inserted into.

However, the last column in the table isn't being found by SQLite for some reason.

Error:

```
OperationalError: table A has no column named Byte
```

My code is below:

```
# Create the table
c.execute("DROP TABLE A;");

c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS A 
        (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        Col1 TEXT,
        Col2 INTEGER,
        Col3 TEXT,
        Col4 TEXT,
        Byte TEXT);""");

# Insert data into A
c.execute("""INSERT INTO A 
                    (Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Byte) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)""",
                    (Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Byte));
```

Note: The values Col1,...,Col4, Byte are computed by my program and hence I'll need a dynamic way of doing this.

Also, where is the table A stored on my disk? Will I be able to query it using `c.execute("SELECT * FROM A;");` without having to rerun the `CREATE TABLE` command after creating `A`?

I keep getting the same error for Byte every time and I'm not sure why. Any insight/general tips will be appreciated.

Comment: Missed a comma when creating the table which led to the last column not being recognised. Voted a top answer anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code does not run in the proposed variant. First of all, remove the comment line from query string. This code works well for me:

```
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect('test.db')

c = con.cursor()
c.execute("DROP TABLE A;")

#computing values
Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Byte = ('1234', 2, '5678', 'qwerty', 'bytestr')

c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS A
    (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    Col1 TEXT,
    Col2 INTEGER,
    Col3 TEXT,
    Col4 TEXT,
    Byte TEXT);""")


# Insert data into A
c.execute("""INSERT INTO A
                (Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Byte) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)""",
                (Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Byte))

c.execute('SELECT * FROM A;')

print c.fetchall() #[(1, u'1234', 2, u'5678', u'qwerty', u'bytestr')]
```

Table 'A' stored in a file 'test.db'. In this case, 'test.db' kept the same folder with the script. If you load this file, and it will have a table 'A', you can execute queries to table 'A' at once. In this case, an attempt to re-create the table will cause an error.

Comment: The values being inserted into A are computed values from my python program. I can't hard code these value in. I'll need a method to insert my values dynamically. The comment is just for people's reference and is not in my actual code.

Comment: I was missing a comma between the second last and the last field when creating the table.

Answer (score 3):

My observation thus far tells that if you modify the names of the columns without dropping the table(deleting the table) which contained the old name, it will slap you with an error.

Note: I know you've called **c.execute("DROP TABLE A;")**, the reason why I typed this out is to make it apparent that this could be one of the many reasons why you're getting an error despite having done everything right.

***In a nutshell, delete the table and create a new one if you have modified the column names.. If deleting the table is not a viable option, revert the column names and things would work the same as they used to.***